# How can I exit a `kubectl exec` command that has frozen due to a network error?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

Sometimes, I'll have a terminal tab with `kubectl exec bash` running in it to check on a container or tail a log file.  When I shut my laptop, turn on my VPN, or just lose Wi-Fi for a second, that terminal can sometimes freeze and leave me unable to exit it without closing the terminal tab or killing the process manually.

I know that SSH sessions have an enter-tilda-period key combo that lets you quit in just this situation, but this doesn't seem to work for `kubectl exec`.  Is there any similar way to accomplish this in this situation?

Comment: I would say it is more related to your terminal, then anything else.

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear what is the root of the problem causing abnormal hang ups of [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/) exec command.

Getting back to your question, you can force to drop the connection and return control of (docker) terminal
back to your hands by setting: `--request-timeout=<value>` to the kubectl command line:

`kubectl exec --request-timeout=5s bash`

It is possible to force termination of kubectl exec by sending -9 signal using kill command.

`kill -9 $(pidof kubectl)`

Comment: question was about terminating interactive session, not timeout the command.

Comment: In my case, a simple `pkill -f kubectl` (i.e., a `TERM` signal) did the trick, and `-9` wasn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try as follows.

```
kubectl --request-timeout=10s
```

[0][https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/#options]

Or you might need to implement functions like below. [1]

[1][http://fibrevillage.com/sysadmin/236-how-to-timeout-a-command-in-linux-shell]

Answer (score 1):

you just need to run this

```
exit
```

Comment: Useful to exit out of a running exec session